# How do you parallelize lazily read information from stdin in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, pipeline

I'm working with this code I wrote, and for some reason threadscope keeps telling me that it's almost never using more than one core at a time. I think the problem is that in order to get the second line it needs to fully evaluate the first line, but I can't figure out an easy way to get it to read in 11 lines at a time.

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import Control.DeepSeq

process :: [String] -> [String]
process lines = do
    let xs = map (\x -> read x :: Double) lines
        ys = map (\x -> 1.0 / (1.0 + (exp (-x)))) xs
        retlines = map (\x -> (show x ) ++ "\n") ys
    retlines

main :: IO ()
main = do
    c <- getContents
    let xs = lines c
        ys = (process xs) `using` parBuffer 11 rdeepseq
    putStr (foldr (++) [] ys)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading this code right, `parBuffer n` only sparks the first `n` elements -- all the rest are evaluated in the usual Haskell way.

```
parBuffer :: Int -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
parBuffer n strat = parBufferWHNF n . map (withStrategy strat)

parBufferWHNF :: Int -> Strategy [a]
parBufferWHNF n0 xs0 = return (ret xs0 (start n0 xs0))
  where -- ret :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
           ret (x:xs) (y:ys) = y `par` (x : ret xs ys)
           ret xs     _      = xs

        -- start :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
           start 0   ys     = ys
           start !_n []     = []
           start !n  (y:ys) = y `par` start (n-1) ys
```

Note in particular that `start 0 ys = ys` and not, say, `` start 0 ys = evaluateThePreviousChunk `pseq` start n0 ys `` or something that would start up more sparks. The documentation definitely doesn't make this clear -- I don't think "rolling buffer strategy" obviously implies this behavior, and I agree it's a bit surprising, to the point that I wonder whether this is just a bug in the `parallel` library that nobody caught yet.

You probably want `parListChunk` instead.